# Iframe prevents me to scroll when the cursor is over it

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe in a webpage, and when my cursor is over it, the parent window doesn't scroll. We don't need to scroll in my iframe and I also added the attribute `scrolling = "no"`. My iframe is an Angular 4 app.

Do you have a solution for my issue? I tried many things but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden` for the body in the iframe.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, it changed nothing.

Comment: [No](https://jsfiddle.net/9k3tLsof/)? In any case, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) `scrolling` attribute is not implemented in HTML5 ...

Comment: That's strange... I'm going to remove this attribute then, maybe the issue is here. Thanks